# css: issue with images when browser zoomed

Tags: css, image, html, overlap

My webpage is "powerpoint style", consists of 100% height slides one under the other.

```
<div id="slide1" class="whitepage">
    <div class="content">
    ....
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide2" class="blackpage">
    <div class="content">
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on. The css is below:

```
body{
text-align:center;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.whitepage{
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background: white;
min-height: auto;
min-width: 1024px;
color: black;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.blackpage{
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
background: black;
min-height: auto;
min-width: 1024px;
color: white;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.content{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center; 
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 1024px;
border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

With this css each slide loads at 100% height (display visible area) and it's ok. Let's imagine that .content consists of a single .png image. If zoom the browser at 150% or more, or if I resize the browser window making it smaller (height) the image overruns in the following slide, but I'd like that the page containing the image extends itself downward in order to contain the image properly. I can get this if I use generic text instead of an image in .content. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take `width=100%` for `.content` and in the image the height and width should be present. Also try using `width` at the palace of `min-width`.

Comment: Tried, no changes :( The image ovveruns the previous slide and the following. With only text in .content it still works.

Comment: To explain better: if .content consists of some text, if I zoom the browser the text becomes bigger and bigger and pulls down the lower end of .content, so the slide becomes more than 100% height, and this is ok; if .content consists of an image, if I zoom the browser the image becomes bigger and bigger and overflows on the following div, and this is not ok.